# ¿Cómo obtener párrafo con más caracateres en javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas, estoy tratando de corregir este script, que intento hacer de forma iterativa, me muestra el párrafo con mayor cantidad de caracteres

```
var parrafos = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML.length;
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML.length;
var p3 = document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML.length;
var p4 = document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML.length;
var p5 = document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML.length;
// alert("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es = " + p5);

function mas_letras() {
  for(var i=0; i<=parrafos.length; i++) {
    if (p1>p2 && p1>p3 && p1>p4 && p1>p5) {
      alert("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es = " + p1);
      if(p2>p3 && p2>p4 && p2>p5){
        alert("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es = " + p2);
        if(p3>p2 && p3>p4 && p3>p5){
          alert("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es = " + p3);
          if(p4>p5){
            alert("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es = " + p4);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      alert("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es = " + p5);
    }
  }
}
```

En el ejercicio que ando realizando, el párrafo que tiene mayor cantidad de caracteres es el ultimo, por lo cual se ejecuta perfectamente, pero cuando aumento los caracteres en los párrafos del medio, no sucede nada, es decir, solo funciona el primer if. Me gustaría saber cuales son los errores que tengo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Podría emplear `Math.max(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)` para obtener el mayor , pero además tiene un error de lógica , debería emplear `else if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes errores lógicos,como por ejemplo :

- Si haces la comparación no es necesario hacerlo dentro de un `for` *sería necesario si se empleara otra forma*
- Las estructuras de control deberían ser `else if` dado que con `if` así se cumpla una condición seguirá comprobando las siguientes condicionales que puede que retorne `true` y muestre el mensaje erróneo.

El código quedaría :

```js
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML.length;
var p2 = document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML.length;
var p3 = document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML.length;
var p4 = document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML.length;
var p5 = document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML.length;
function mas_letras() {

    if (p1>p2 && p1>p3 && p1>p4 && p1>p5) 
        console.log("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es  p1= " + p1);
    else if(p2>p1 && p2>p3 && p2>p4 & p2>p5)
        console.log("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es p2 = " + p2);
    else if(p3>p1 && p3>p2 && p3>p4 &&  p3>p5)
        console.log("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es p3= " + p3);
    else if(p4>p1 && p4>p2 && p4>p3 &&  p4>p5)
        console.log("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es p4= " + p4);
    else if(p5>p1 && p5>p2 && p5>p3 &&  p5>p4)
      console.log("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es p5  = " + p5);

}
mas_letras();
```

```html
<p id="p1">AAAAAA</p>
<p id="p2">CCCC</p>
<p id="p3">AAAAA</p>
<p id="p4">BBBB</p>
<p id="p5">AAA</p>
```

Para encontrar el mayor podría haber empleado simplemente

```
 Math.max(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)
```

De forma iterativa sería así , además de imprimir el valor mayor , se imprime el elemento por si acaso más adelante decide acceder a este.

```js
function mas_letras(parrafos) {
    var mayor = parrafos[0]; 
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < parrafos.length; i++) {
        if(parrafos[i].innerText.length>mayor.innerText.length){
            result.push((i+1));
            mayor=parrafos[i];
            result.push(mayor.innerText.length);
        }
    }
    if(result.length==0){
      result.push(1);
      result.push(mayor.innerText.length);
    }
    return result;
}
var parrafos = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var resultado = mas_letras(parrafos);
console.log("El Parrafo que tiene más caracteres es de " + resultado[1] + " Y es el Parrafo número "+ resultado[0]);
```

```html
<p id="p1">AAAAAA</p>
<p id="p2">CCCC</p>
<p id="p3">AAAAA</p>
<p id="p4">BBBBB</p>
<p id="p5">AAA</p>
```

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer de forma iterativa el script, me faltó colocar eso en la pregunta, pido disculpas.

Comment: @JuanRomero cuál sería el comportamiento si se encuentran valores iguales?

Comment: ,bueno, ninguno,no coteje esa opción porque todos están desiguales

Comment: @JuanRomero verificar mi respuesta entonces. :)

Comment: @Dev. Joel con **Math.max( P1, ... )** puedes obtener el numero máximo pero como saber a quien corresponde?

Comment: @fwBasic tomé en cuenta ese detalle en la segunda opción. lo del `Math.max` lo coloqué dado que en su `if else` nunca sabía el elemento  si no solo su valor. para ese caso particular donde solo se quería obtener el máximo valor , se podría emplear el `Math.max()`

Comment: @Dev. Joel y si quisiera el valor de **i** para saber el párrafo del que tiene mas caracteres?  , por cierto, muchas gracias por la ayuda, fue bastante útil.

Comment: @JuanRomero con la segunda opción puedes obtener el párrafo con más  caracteres. ya que retorno el elemento :)

Comment: @Dev. Joel, pregunte mal, quiero decir la posición, ya se de el párrafo que tiene mas caracteres, mi pregunta es saber el número de el, ejemplo: " el párrafo que tiene mas caracteres es de **800** palabras y es el párrafo número **3**" , es el **3** que vendría siendo el valor de **i** por el que pregunto ahora.

Comment: @JuanRomero verificar mi actualización para la segunda opción. igual se puede mejorar pero ahora ando corto de tiempo. espero le ayude. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacerlo iterativo es agregando el evento `onChange` a cada elemento **html** y luego compararlo con los elementos de igual (o mayor) tamaño.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".parrafo").forEach(function(e){
 e.addEventListener("change",Parrafo);
})

function Parrafo(){
 var parrafos = maxLen(".parrafo"), tmp="";
 parrafos.forEach(function(e){
  tmp += ", "+e.id;
 })
 alert("el parrafo con mayor cantidad de letras es = " + tmp.substr(2));
}

function maxLen(selector){
 var parrafos = "";
 document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(function(e){
  if (parrafos == "" || e.value.length > parrafos[0].value.length){
   parrafos = [e];
  } else if (e.value.length == parrafos[0].value.length){
   parrafos.push(e);
  }
 });
 return parrafos;
}
```

```html
<input id="p1" class="parrafo">
<input id="p2" class="parrafo">
<input id="p3" class="parrafo">
<input id="p4" class="parrafo">
<input id="p5" class="parrafo">
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: La función "Parrafo" la cambiaría a "procesarParrafo" o algo similar - sería confuso para alguien mas que lee tu código :)

Comment: Tu comentario menosprecia la capacidad de comprensión de los demás, sin embargo fíjate que tu lo entendiste.